# Using Partial<T> in TypeScript for flexible initialisation

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use an `init` parameter of `Partial<T>` type in the constructor to make initialisation more flexible. Here is my code:

```
export class Team {
    id: string;
    name: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Team>) {

    }
}

const team = new Team({});
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error though:

```
Argument of type {} is not assignable to parameter type Partial<Team>
```

Comment: Code works fine for me.

Comment: Tried compiling in command line and it works, but my IDE still gives me that error, so it's and IDE problem.